# Multiple <script> tags?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, tags, script-tag

I am Using a WordPress Plugin called OptinLinks, which gives me snippets to include in my HTML files. They will make an email opt-in form pop up.

Now, I have three buttons in one , for which I want to add a  each.
However, when testing only the first one will make an opt-in form show up.
If you click on the other button, nothing happens.

```
<div class="mbr-section-btn">
    <!-- snippet 1 the plugin gave me: seems to work -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.pks-internet.com/wp-content/plugins/opt/admin_pages/ajax/remote.php?opt_link=4&opt_container_id=optinlinks_7f23_4"></script><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="optinlinks_7f23_4 btn btn-lg btn-black">DOG OWNER</a>
    <!-- snippet 2 the plugin gave me: doesn't work -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.pks-internet.com/wp-content/plugins/opt/admin_pages/ajax/remote.php?opt_link=5&opt_container_id=optinlinks_7f23_5"></script><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="optinlinks_7f23_5 btn btn-lg btn-black">CAT OWNER</a>
    <!-- snippet 3 the plugin gave me: doesn't work-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.pks-internet.com/wp-content/plugins/opt/admin_pages/ajax/remote.php?opt_link=6&opt_container_id=optinlinks_7f23_6"></script><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="optinlinks_7f23_6 btn btn-lg btn-black">DOG &amp; CAT OWNER</a>
</div>
```

Why does the first one work only? How can I get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

my guess would be to download the script and save it into different filenames for each respective script tag. If that doesn't work, change a little bit of the code on each different file in a way that would not mess it up.

Comment: Thanks for the idea Maxim, so you would just go to the links and save them as separate *.js files, did I understand that correctly?

How would the code of the button look like then in order to make those codes work when clicking it?

Comment: Well, for the `src` tag, you would replace the links with the links of the new files you saved.